# iBus-Unikey, I cant transfor between English and Vietnamese on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ibus

I have a trouble with iBus-unikey, I installed it for ubuntu 12.04 and it worked correctly. I can transform between English and Vietnamese.

But when I upgrade my OS up ubuntu 14.04 I cant transform between English and Vietnamese. It always in Vietnamese and so I cant type my password in the terminal.

I don't know how to use iBus-Unikey in 14.04. It is different from Ubuntu 12.04. Please help me if you know about it!

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings → Language Support, click on "Install/Removes Languagues...", make sure Vietnamese is installed, if not then check it and click OK. Also, make sure IBus is selected in the "Keyboard input method system" part.

Go back to System Settings and click "Text Entry". Click on "+" and add "Vietnamese (Unikey)". Now can change between Vietnamese and English using Super+Space

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble though I use Korean.

I've solved it as the below way:

1. Open "System Settings".
2. Enter "Text Entry".

   (My ubuntu menu text is not English but Korean. So I don't know the exact name of the menu. But you can find it easily. The follow image is for it.)

[image]
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF4Us.png

3. In my case, there is no "English(US)" in the list for "input sources to use". Mine has only "Korean".

   So I added "English(US)" and then I've been able to change my input source between Korean and English.

I wish you can solve this trouble with my way.

Good luck! :-)